# Rails 3.1: for some reason generators now creating .js and not .js.coffee files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Any one know why my Rails (3.1rc5) generators aren't creating CoffeeScript "templates" anymore?

Instead of:

```
  $ rails g controller sessions new
  create  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
   route  get "sessions/new"
  invoke  haml
  create    app/views/sessions
  create    app/views/sessions/new.html.haml
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
  invoke  assets
  create    app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js.coffee  ##### <- HERE
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/sessions.css.scss
```

I get:

```
  $ rails g controller sessions new
  ...
  invoke  assets
  invoke    js
  create      app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js
  ...
```

Comment: Do you have `gem 'coffee-script'` in your Gemfile? Have you `bundle install`d since you added it?

Comment: yes and yes! it's a "native" 3.1 app... *created in 3.1rc1* and `.coffee` files were generated for all the controllers...until today when it generating `.js`.  The `invoke js` line in the console feedback must mean something...cuz it's not there in the earlier CoffeeScript example... so, **what is "invoking" js?**

Comment: Could you show us your Gemfile, without it i'ts kinda hard to know what might be the issue.